# Problems with e-mail validation Regex on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, email

I've just started to learn how to use Regex and I'm trying to create a regex to validate an e-mail adress in Ruby. This is what I got so far:

```
emailregex = /([a-zA-Z]+([_\-.][a-zA-Z]*)*@\D+[.]\D+)/
str = "abc_def@hotmail.com"
puts str.scan emailregex
```

Expected Output:

```
abc_def@hotmail.com
```

Actual Output:

```
abc_def@hotmail.com
_def
```

I've seen a few e-mail regex validations, but I want to know what is wrong with my regex. Thanks in advice.

Comment: You could use a first line of defense filter regex from http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address, which is `^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$` then send a verification email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scan will output only the capture groups if at least 1 capture group (...) is in the regex.

That regex has 2 capture groups, and `_def` is the last occurence of the inner capture group.
You could make the inner a non-capturing group (?:...) to avoid that.

For example:

```
str = "emails : abc_def@hotmail.com x_y_z@hotmail.com" 
emailregex = /([a-zA-Z]+(?:[_.-][a-zA-Z]*)*@\S+[.]\S+)/ 
puts str.scan emailregex
```

Outputs:

```
abc_def@hotmail.com
x_y_z@hotmail.com
```

Btw, scan can be usefull to get an array of matches from a text based on a pattern.
But to actually validate a string against a pattern? There's another way.

Example:

```
emailregex = /^[a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)*$/i

puts ("Papa.Smurf@smurfs.town" =~ emailregex ? true : false)

puts ("Joda.says:email.is.not" =~ emailregex ? true : false)
```

Comment: It is worth it mention that `String#scan` always returns an array, even if `puts` outputs just a string.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It’s [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) not `Regexp`, who is to blame. Check:

```
str = "abc_def@hotmail.com"
str.scan /\w+/
#⇒ ["abc_def", "hotmail", "com"]
```

You probably want to e.g. use `String#[]`:

```
str[emailregex]
#⇒ "abc_def@hotmail.com"
```

But please don’t use a regular expression to match emails and [here is why](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). Sooner or later your regexp-based validation will fail. To validate the email *just check for `@` in the string and send the validation email there*. This is the only valid modern way to validate emails.